# On confluent hypergeomtric differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

The confluent hypergeometric series with parameter $(a,b)$ is

$$F(a,b,x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_kx^k}{(b)_kk!},$$

where $(a)_n=a(a+1)\cdots (a+n-1)$ is the Pochhammer symbol. Prove that $F$ satisfies the differential equation

$$xf''(x)+(b-x)f'(x)-af(x)=0.$$

I tried to substitute the series into the differential equation, but then I dont see how the terms can cancel and vanish, someone please helps, thank you very much.

Comment: It should simplify quite nicely if you use the fact that $\frac{(a)_k}{(a)_{k-1}} = a + k - 1$ a couple of times.

Comment: sorry, i still cannot work it out. Here is my work:

$$F'= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_kx^{k-1}}{(b)_k (k-1)!}$$
$$F''= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_kx^{k-2}}{(b)_k (k-2)!}$$

So that 

$$xF''+(b-x)F'-aF$$
$$= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_{k+2}x^{k+1}}{(b)_{k+2}k!}+\frac{(a)_{k+1}(b-x)x^{k}}{(b)_{k+}k!}-\frac{(a)_{k}ax^{k}}{(b)_{k}k!}$$

Comment: The fraction becomes

$$(\frac{(a)_{k+2}}{(b)_{k+2}}-\frac{(a)_{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}}) \frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}+(\frac{b(a)_{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}}-\frac{a(a)_{k}}{(b)_{k}})\frac{x^{k}}{k!}$$, which did not canceled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_kx^k}{(b)_kk!}$$
$$F' = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_{k+1}x^k}{(b)_{k+1}k!}$$
$$F'' = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_{k+2}x^k}{(b)_{k+2}k!}$$

Hence :
\begin{eqnarray*}
ODE &=& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_{k+2}x^{k+1}}{(b)_{k+2}k!} + b\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_{k+1}x^k}{(b)_{k+1}k!} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_{k+1}x^{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}k!} - a\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_{k}x^k}{(b)_{k}k!}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{k+2}}{(b)_{k+2}} - \frac{(a)_{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}}\bigg] + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\bigg[b\frac{(a)_{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}} - a\frac{(a)_{k}}{(b)_{k}}\bigg]\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}}\frac{a+k+1}{b+k+1} - \frac{(a)_{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}}\bigg] + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{k}}{(b)_{k}}\frac{b(a+k)}{b+k} - a\frac{(a)_{k}}{(b)_{k}}\bigg]\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}}\frac{a - b}{b+k+1}\bigg] + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{k}}{(b)_{k}}\frac{k(b-a)}{b+k}\bigg]\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}}\frac{a - b}{b+k+1}\bigg] + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{k}}{(b)_{k}}\frac{k(b-a)}{b+k}\bigg]\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}}\frac{a - b}{b+k+1}\bigg] + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{(k-1)!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{k}}{(b)_{k}}\frac{b-a}{b+k}\bigg]\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{k+1}}{(b)_{k+1}}\frac{a - b}{b+k+1}\bigg] + \sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s+1}}{s!}\bigg[\frac{(a)_{s+1}}{(b)_{s+1}}\frac{b-a}{b+s+1}\bigg]\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray*}

I went slowly. Each step is a small calculation so you should be able to understand it all. The last step is zero because they are the same but with opposite signs $a-b$ in the first and $b-a$ in the second. Also I let $s+1 = k$ in the end.

Comment: thank you so much for typesetting it! im really grateful